# Uniform convergence of Taylor series

Tags: complex-analysis, uniform-convergence

I am trying to show:

If $f: B(0,R) \to \mathbb C$ is analytic then the Taylor series of $f$ at $0$ converges uniformly to $f$ in $B(0,r)$ for all $r\in (0,R)$

But I got stuck with my proof. Please can somebody help me? Here is what I have so far:

From [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Analyticity_of_holomorphic_functions) I have 
$$ f(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n {1\over 2 \pi i}\int_C {f(w) \over w^{n+1}}dw$$

Therefore the Taylor series of $f$ at $0$ is

$T_0(z) = \sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n c_n$

where $c_n = {1\over 2 \pi i}\int_C {f(w) \over w^{n+1}}dw$.

My idea is to apply the Weierstrass $M$-test [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weierstrass_M-test) for $f_n(x) = z^n c_n$. It holds that $|z^n| < r^n$ and $|c_n|\le {M \over r^n}$ and therefore $|f_n(z)|\le M$. The problem is how to show

$\sum_{n=0}^\infty M < \infty$? It is obviously not true (consider $R=1$). Where is my mistake?

Comment: Use *two* radiuses, $r$ and $r+\epsilon$.

Comment: There is no reason to use a radius of $r$ for the circle $C$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have to show, that $\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n c_n$ is unformly convergent for $|z|<r$. The trick is, that $C\subset B(0,R)$ can be any smooth closed curve rounding the origin. So take $\varrho$ such that $r<\varrho<R$ and let $C:=\{z\,|\,|z|=\varrho\}=\{\varrho e^{it}\,|\,0\leq t\leq 2\pi\}$. Then 
$$
|c_n| =\left|{1\over 2 \pi i}\int_C {f(w) \over w^{n+1}}dw\right|\leq \frac{1}{2\pi}\int_C\frac{|f(w)|}{\varrho^{n+1}}|dw|\leq \max_{w\in C}|f(w)|\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_0^{2\pi}\frac{1}{\varrho^{n+1}}\varrho\,dt=\max_{w\in C}|f(w)|\frac{1}{\varrho^n}.
$$
Thus it follows 
$$
\left|\sum_{n=0}^\infty z^n c_n\right|\leq\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \max_{w\in C}|f(w)|\frac{r^n}{\varrho^n}=\max_{w\in C}|f(w)|\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\frac{r}{\varrho}\right)^n=\max_{w\in C}|f(w)|\frac{1}{1-(r/\varrho)}.
$$
(Here we used that $0<(r/\varrho)<1$.)

Answer (score 1):

You basically have the right ideas. Let instead of using a circle of radius $r$ for your contours, use a radius that is slightly bigger. That is, let $C = \{ z\in \mathbb{C}: |z| = r'\}$, where $r < r' < R$.

With this, you'll have a convergent geometric series as the upper bound for $\sum |f_n(z)|$.

Comment: Thank you. Please can you say more? I don't understand how bigger radius results in convergence of $\sum |f_n (x)|$.

Comment: The bigger radius gives a better bound for the *integral*.

Comment: @blue You have $|z|^n<r^n$ and $|c_n| < \dfrac{M}{(r‘)^n}$. So $|f_n(z)|<M \left(\dfrac{r}{r‘}\right)^n$. Note that $r/r'<1$